# Firebase hosting connect to cloud function in *europe-west1*

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have an api set up on Google Cloud Functions (https://europe-west1-myproject-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/v1/ical.ics). 
This works well, but I wish to set up a "friendly" domain name for the api.  :)

According to Googles [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) this is seems easy, but it does not seem to work for cloud functions outside the USA, eg. europe-west1.

I have updated the `firebase.json` file with the below code according to documentation.

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "api"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

When accessing https://myproject-name.web.app/api/v1/ical.ics 
I get redirected to https://us-central1-myproject-name.cloudfunctions.net/api/api/v1/cal.ics with error 403 and the below error message.

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /api/api/ical.ics from this server.
```

I must be overlooking something really basic here, since this seems like a really easy operation? :)

Kind regards
/K

Comment: There is no workaround. It's just not supported outside of us-central1.

Comment: This is unfortunate for many people. One thing is data rules (gdpr), another thing is very serious latency issues when having functions running in the US while hosting/db is elsewhere (Europe for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions) (see blue text block):

> If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for Firebase
>   Hosting, you **must use us-central1**.

---

You will also find a similar warning in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) you refer to in your question about "Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Functions" (See blue text block as well):

> Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer! I will certainly try that. \(^__^)/

Comment: Be vary of GDPR restrictions when feeding data through a US data center.

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely the answer you are looking for since it is not possible with Firebase Hosting.
But it is possible to get a custom domain in front of your cloud functions hosted in EU by using `Cloud Run`.
I followed this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions

And after that i added the custom domain under the `Manage custom domains` on [Cloud Run](https://console.cloud.google.com/run).

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly look into possibly using a custom domain and Cloud Run! /K